# iOS Argument labels '(named:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift

i get the error in this line after i modified it

```
 let CS = User(name: "Sporting Club", images: RoundImage(named: "1.png")! , coordinate:(41.844326 , 12.467619), type: "Sport", address: "Via dei Cocchieri, 1A")
```

by changing

```
images: UIImage(named: "1.png")!
```

with

```
images: RoundImage(named: "1.png")!
```

a custom class to have circular images; before the change the code work perfectly but now i get this error, someone can explain me how to solve it?

the class of RoundImage is this

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RoundImage: UIImageView {



    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sure someone can explain once you post your RoundImage class

Comment: `RoundImage` extends `UIImageView`, not `UIImage`. So `RoundImage` gets all of the `init` methods from `UIImageView` which does not have one called `init(named:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RoundImage` is a subclass of `UIImageView`. `UIImageView` has no `init(named:)` initializer.

Perhaps you meant to subclass `UIImage`, not `UIImageView`. However, `UIImage` has no `layer` property, so your inspectable properties won't compile.

Your `User` class shouldn't know anything about the view hierarchy. Its initializer should not take a view parameter. A `User` object shouldn't care that its image is displayed in a round view.

I suggest three changes:

1. Your `User` initializer should take a plain `UIImage`.
2. You should rename your `RoundImage` class to `RoundImageView`.
3. You should use a `RoundImageView` in your view hierarchy.